# PHP - Wrap a variable block in the same try-catch

Tags: php, error-handling, code-reuse

in my PHP project, I use Guzzle to make a lot of different API requests. In order to handle all exception, each API call is wrapped into a try-catch block. An example:

```
        try {
            $res = $client->get($url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => "bearer " . $jwt,
                ]
            ]);
        } catch (ClientException $clientException) {
            // Do stuff
        } catch (ConnectException $connectException) {
            // Do stuff
        }catch (RequestException $requestException){
            // Do stuff
        }
```

For each request, the exceptiuon handling is the same but the actual execution block differs a lot and can not be simply described by an array of options.

Is there a way to create a function/class able to wrap a custom execution block into the same try-catch handling?

The only options I came up with is to use an interface with a function `execution()` that is extended by each child and a function `run()` that has the try-catch blocks and simply calls `$this->execution()` inside the execution block. It would work, but I found too verbose the creation of a whole new class for each different API call that is only used in one point of my project.

Is there a better/less verbose solution to avoid code repetition of the same exception handling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass a callable, which can be [an anonymous function, a regular function, or a class method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
function executeGuzzle(callable $fun) {
    try {
        return $fun();
    } catch (ClientException $clientException) {
        // Do stuff
    } catch (ConnectException $connectException) {
        // Do stuff
    } catch (RequestException $requestException) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

$res = executeGuzzle(function () use ($client) {
    return $client->get(...);
});
```